# NullPointerException on back press in fragment with nested google map fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an activity which displays content using several fragments. One of these fragments needs to display a google map fragment inside it. I have got the map fragment displaying correctly with the code below and the app works fine transitioning between different fragments, however, every time I exit the app by pressing the back button from the fragment with the map, I get an android error alert message and the following nullpointerexception error in logcat. The log response does not point to anywhere in my code where i can handle the exception. I think the problem lies with the ondestroyView() method but i dont know enough about fragments at the moment to fix it. Any ideas?

Logcat error:

```
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1410)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-10 14:15:42.888: E/AndroidRuntime(15039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the fragment where the error occurs:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public HomeFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}  


public void onDestroyView() {

    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainmap));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

The xml for the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg">

    <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/mainmap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Section of MainActivity class which controls fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

    }


    // Display fragment view 
    private void displayView(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:         
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new PromotionsFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            break; 
        default:
            break;
        }


        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Fragment creation error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then the question arises, if you want to exit the application, why you remove fragment if Activity will be destroyed anyway

Comment: I found when transitioning between fragments I was getting an InflateException if i didnt remove the map fragment on destroy.

Comment: I am also having same problem did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 6):

I had face same problem after a long research i found below answer:-

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (!getActivity().isFinishing())
    {
        if (f != null)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove UI element if it was declared in XML file. If you want certain elements to be removable you must add them from code, not have them in XML. Also there's no point of removing it in your `onDestroyView` you haven't added in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to initialize FragmentManager and Fragment as global variables
This was what i've done, and worked for me:

```
private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Fragment fragment = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Add FragmentManager as static field in your class

```
    private static FragmentManager mFragmentManagerSupport; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          mFragmentManagerSupport = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

          ....

      }
```

and when you first call fragment, you need call "add" or "replace" method like this.

```
    mFragmentManagerSupport.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
        .commit();
```

Without this your fragmentmanager will have 0 fragments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, hasnt fixed it though. My code in my MainActivity where I initialize the fragments is already like this. The only difference is my code doesnt use a static FragmentManager. I added the static field to see if it would work but nothing changed.

Comment: just updated my question to include the relevant parts of my MainActivity class.